# Scanset doesn't recognize carriage return in c, why?

Tags: c, scanf

I am trying to take input up to a carriage return press with scanset, that is the enter button press.( which on windows equals to \r\n , right? ). now this works if I write `%[^\n]` inside scanf() , but not for `%[^\r]` which to my understanding should also work. So what is the catch here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[120];

    scanf("%[^\r]", str);

    printf("%s",str);
}
```

Comment: Use a maximum field width, `scanf` cannot magically know how big the buffer is: `scanf("%119[^\r]", str);`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are reading from standard input. Standard input is a *text* input stream. In text input streams the end of line is indicated by the `\n` character regardless of whether it happens "on Windows" or not. The purpose of *text* input stream, among other things, is to make sure that by the time the input data gets to `scanf`, that data is already translated into a platform-independent form with regard to line endings at least. "On Windows" the `\r\n` combination is already replaced with a lone `\n` by the time it gets to your `scanf`. You can't see `\r\n` by reading standard Windows input with `scanf` (that is unless you are reading a Windows text file using Unix input stream).

Comment: Hmm. So another question to just be sure I understand it properly. When I use a function like getchar() it can read '\r' character. Why is that? Does it only happen with scanf()?

Comment: It doesn't depend on the function, but on the underlying stream. Read the `fopen` documentation for more information (or look for _text streams_ and _binary streams_).

Comment: @prithul: I don't know how you managed to see `\r` even with `getchar()`. I just tried it and in my experiment `getchar()` reads `\n` and nothing else. If you read a Windows text file by using Unix standard library (i.e. Unix version of `getchar()`), then you will see `\r\n` at the end of each line. But Windows's own `getchar()` should not see that `\r`.

Comment: That was a mistake from my part saying getchar(). I actually tried with getche(). Yes I know that is not a standard function. But am trying to find why does it work for getche(). Does it use a different stream?

Comment: @prithul: Well, I'd guess that `_getche` does not work with standard input stream at all. It looks like a function intended to read input directly from keyboard. Or, if it does work with standard input, it might read it at lower (raw) level, where the end-of-line translation has not occured yet.

Comment: I checked the docs, it is said to be reading from standard input stream. So it must be the case that it is read before the conversion has taken place. I don't have proof to support that though.